# Выбор паттерна проектирования для простого пет проекта

Tags: python, python-3.x, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть небольшой пет проект, который хочу переписать, используя паттерн, но никак не могу понять/определиться какой именно паттерн луше использовать.

Что делает программа? На вход подаётся ссылка:

1. Ссылка приводится к валидному виду, для получения ответа в виде json
2. Делаем запрос и получаем json
3. В этом json содержаться ссылки на необходимые объекты, извлекаем их

Главная идея состит в том, чтобы всё было понятно и структурировано и не было такого:

```
def start(user_url):
    valid_url = build_valid_url(user_url)
    doc = get_json(valid_url)
    all_url = get_all_url(doc)
    return all_url
```

Какой паттерн стоит использовать в данном случае?

Comment: Ну можете в одну строчку написать, зачем вам промежуточные переменные? ))  Нормальный код, главное, чтобы сами эти функции тоже были короткими и понятными, отрефакторенными в несколько ясных строчек.

Comment: Как вариант можете в класс функции-методы спрятать. Входной `url` передавать классу при создании, потом из класса получаете ссылки каким-то методом. А всё остальное внутри класса происходит, включая препроцессинг `url`-я.